# access variables in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, soap, hash, savon

I have a Savon SOAP session where I get a response that is converted to an array. Part of this response is then stored in an variable package containing a hash like this;

```
{
  :cancellation_policies=>nil,
  :contract_id=>"834",
  :hotel_id=>"41298",
  :package_id=>"6b0938e-bf45ed4facda",
  :package_price=>{
    :currency=>"NOK",
    :final_price=>"1400.05",
    :final_price_in_supplier_currency=>"169",
    :original_price=>"1400.05", 
    :original_price_in_supplier_currency=>"169",
    :supplier_currency=>"GBP"
  },
  :rooms=>{
    :room=>{
      :adults_count=>"2",
      :availability=>"Available",
      :description=>{
        :"@xmlns:a"=>"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
      },
      :id=>"6de98b4b-256e-47de-bbd3-700602a16e8e",
      :kids_ages=>{
        :"@xmlns:a"=>"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
      },
      :price=>{
        :currency=>"NOK",
        :final_price=>"1419.05",
        :final_price_in_supplier_currency=>"165",
        :original_price=>"1419.05",
        :original_price_in_supplier_currency=>"165",
        :supplier_currency=>"GBP"
      },
      :room_basis=>"Bed and Breakfast BB",
      :room_basis_original=>"Room and Breakfast (American Buffet Breakfast)", 
      :room_class=>"Standard",
      :room_class_original=>"Double Room",
      :room_type=>"Double",
      :room_type_original=>"Double Room"
    }
  },
  :supplier_id=>"21",
  :supplier_name=>"HTP"
}
```

The strange thing happens when i try to access package[:cancellation_policies] i get an error saying; can't convert Symbol into Integer.

How do I access for instance :cancellation_policies ?

package.inspect gives;

```
{ :cancellation_policies=>nil, :contract_id=>"834", :hotel_id=>"41298", :package_id=>"4e80e642-13eb-48d6-9f1e-8b35f1c406ca", :package_price=>{:currency=>"NOK", :final_price=>"1677.06", :final_price_in_supplier_currency=>"195", :original_price=>"1677.06", :original_price_in_supplier_currency=>"195", :supplier_currency=>"GBP"}, :rooms=>{:room=>{:adults_count=>"2", :availability=>"Available", :description=>{:"@xmlns:a"=>"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"}, :id=>"dce10420-bbc5-471e-b388-03d6bb132e27", :kids_ages=>{:"@xmlns:a"=>"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"}, :price=>{:currency=>"NOK", :final_price=>"1677.06", :final_price_in_supplier_currency=>"195", :original_price=>"1677.06", :original_price_in_supplier_currency=>"195", :supplier_currency=>"GBP"}, :room_basis=>"Bed and Breakfast BB", :room_basis_original=>"Breakfast (Full Breakfast)", :room_class=>"Standard", :room_class_original=>"Standard Double - Double", :room_type=>"Double", :room_type_original=>"Standard Double - Double"}}, :supplier_id=>"21", :supplier_name=>"HTP"}
```

(As far as I can tell the same output as above?)

So I tried with;

```
<% package.each do |key, value| %>
<%= key %> is <%= value %>
<% end %>
```

which nicely prints
contract_id is 834
hotel_id is 41298

...and so on, if that clarifies anything?

So temporary thing that solves it for me;

```
package_as_hash = Hash.new 
package.each do |key, value|
package_as_hash[key]  = value
end
```

Highly doubt its the most efficient way but at least it works...

Comment: Apparently, `package` is an array and not a hash. Try debug printing more.

Comment: So how should i access for instance supplier_id ?

Comment: And as far as I can tell, package is a hash?

Comment: @hso show us the output of calling `package.inspect`

Comment: calling package.class returns Hash, this might be where the problem is?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev updated the question with package.inspect output.

Comment: @hso please do so immediatley before calling `package[:cancellation_policies]`. It seems a local variable or something is shadowing the Hash. The error you get is as if package is an Array not a Hash.

Comment: you must be doing something with package... what you mean by `I get a response that is converted to an array`?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev this was done immediatley before. Calling package.class returns array. package.first returns[:cancellation_policies, nil]

Comment: @gabrielhilal Just that the response from the soap service was converted had an .to_hash added to it, tried removing ut, but no difference...

Comment: @hso so package is an `Array` as suggested by many users. Also output by inspect can't be as you show if package is an Array.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev adding to_hash directly to package gives; undefined method `to_hash' for [:cancellation_policies, nil]:Array

Comment: @hso that was wrong conclusion made by me. I still don't get what exactly is `package` apparently it is some kind of Array and it seems just calling `package[1]` will give you the result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason your package is not a hash.

If you copy and paste the below in your console:

```
package = {
            :level_1=>"1",
            :rooms=>{
              :level_2=>"2",
              :room=>{
                :level_3=>"3",
              }
            },
          }
```

You will see that you can access any level of your hash:

```
package[:level_1]
=> "1" 
package[:rooms][:level_2]
=> "2" 
package[:rooms][:room][:level_3]
=> "3"
```

However, if by mistake you just change `{` to `[`:

```
package = [
            :level_1=>"1",
            :rooms=>{
              :level_2=>"2",
              :room=>{
                :level_3=>"3",
              }
            },
          ]
```

You will get Array, and it appears to be the error you are facing:

```
package[:level_1]
TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

To solve your problem, you must find out why you have an Array if you were expecting a Hash:

- You can avoid package to became an Array;
- or you can convert your array into a hash. However, to do that, you must understand the structure of your array.

Comment: so is there any way to convert package to something (a string?) and the create the hash with this string?

Comment: it depends on the structure of your array... Can you show the inspect for `package` at the point where it is used (as array)

Comment: for example: `package_as_hash = Hash[*package.collect { |v| [package.index(v), v] }.flatten]` could do the trick